# Long polling in android is blocking port 80

Tags: android, jax-ws, ksoap2, long-polling

I'm using long-polling technique with ksoap like this:

```
HttpTransportSE getMessagesTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);
getMessagesTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

It is working fine if I only have one invocation of the **Web Service** at the same time.
, but if I invoke another Web Service while the other is requested, **it is not called until the other ends**.

It seems **port 80 is blocked in Android client** and only is allowed one request to *`domain:port (domain:80)`*

Is there any way to **increase that number of connections**?

(I preafear don't use Comet arquitechture or Asyn WebServices).

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a generic class to forget in wich version we are. When we create an AsyncTask we always extends of AsyncTaskThreadPool. Hope it helps you!

```
public abstract class AsyncTaskThreadPool<T1, T2, T3> extends AsyncTask<T1, T2, T3> {

    public void ExecuteThreadPool(T1 param)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            this.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, param);
        } else {
            this.execute(param);
        }
    }

    protected abstract T3 doInBackground(T1... params);


}
```

Comment: just comment the param T1 should be "T1... param"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was invoking 2 async tasks and if version of android >= HONEYCOMB you have to execute your async tasks in the threadpool because one locks to other:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        new SendMessageToEventAsync(this, formattedMessageToSend)
                .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
    } else {
        new SendMessageToEventAsync(this, formattedMessageToSend)
                .execute("");
```